# How to derive the formula for angular velocity in three dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

The formula for the velocity of a point $\vec {r}$ with angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ is given by $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$.

But, how can we derive the formula $\vec{\omega}=\frac{\vec{r} \times \vec{v}}{|\vec{r}|^2}$ from the above formula, which is known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\vec v&=\vec \omega \times \vec r\\
\vec r \times \vec v&=\vec r \times (\vec \omega \times \vec r)\\
&=\vec \omega (\vec r \cdot \vec r)-\vec r(\vec r\cdot \vec \omega)^*\\
&=\vec \omega |\vec r|^2~^{**}-0^{***}\\
\frac{\vec r \times \vec v}{|\vec r|^2}&=\vec \omega\\
\end{align}$$

$^*$ [The tripple rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html): $$A\times (B\times C)=B(A\cdot C)-C(A\cdot B)$$

$^{**}$ [Dot product with itself](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dot_Product_of_Vector_with_Itself):

$$A\cdot A=|A|^2$$

$^{***}$ Direction of $\vec \omega$ is out of (or into) the circle plane and thus always perpendicular to any vector drawn on the circle plane. So $\vec r \perp \vec \omega$. [Dot product of perpendicular vectors](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch08/vch08_9.html):

$$A \cdot B=0\qquad \text{for} \quad  A \perp B$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the identity (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251690/a-shorter-way-to-prove-the-identity-on-vectors-veca-veca-cdot-vecn/251713#251713))
$$
{\bf v} = \left({\bf v} \bullet \hat{\bf r}\right) \hat{\bf r} + \left(\hat{\bf r} \times {\bf v}\right) \times \hat{\bf r}
$$
and the fact that ${\bf v} \bullet \hat{\bf r} = \left(\omega \times {\bf r}\right) \bullet \hat{\bf r} = 0$.